# Can I achieve my required rules in SQL OLAP function?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the below scenarios. Not sure if this can be achieved using SQL.

Data:

```
RECORD_SET, DATE_GAP, PREV_Record_start_ts, Bucket 

DIFF Y 01/01/1900 00:00:00 1 

SAME N 12/29/2013 23:59:59 1 

SAME N 02/11/2014 23:59:59 1 

SAME Y 12/22/2014 23:59:59 2 

SAME Y 06/10/2016 23:59:59 3 

SAME N 02/18/2017 23:59:59 3
```

I have to derive the Bucket value based on the below rule:

If Record_Set = DIFF and PREV_RECORD_START_TS=1900 then set bucket to 1
If Record_set=SAME and Data_Gap='N' then set bucket=prev_bucket value else bucket=prev_bucket value+1

Answer (score 2):

You need two things here:

1. CASE statement

`CASE WHEN <conditional expression> THEN <expression> ELSE <other_expression> END`

2. Window function

`MAX(<col_name>) OVER(ORDER BY <ordering_column> ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) -- This will get you the previous row's value for <col_name>`

So, specifically in your scenario:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN Record_set = 'DIFF' AND EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM PREV_RECORD_START_TS) = '1900' THEN 1
    WHEN Record_set = 'SAME' AND DATE_GAP = 'N' THEN MAX(bucket_value) OVER(ORDER BY Prev_Record_Start_ts DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
    ELSE MAX(bucket_value) OVER(ORDER BY Prev_Record_Start_ts DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) + 1
  END AS Bucket
FROM MyTable
```

This assumes that you order your rows using the `Prev_record_start_ts` field.

I don't have access to a TD system to check, so you may have some syntax errors.  But give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of a DENSE_RANK, you can get it using a Cumulative Sum over a CASE similar to ravioli's:

```
select
   sum(case when (Record_Set = 'DIFF' and PREV_RECORD_START_TS= timestamp '1900-01-01 00:00:00')
              or Record_set='SAME' and Data_Gap='N'
            then 1
            else 0
       end)
   over (ORDER BY Prev_Record_Start_ts DESC)
```